# How can I host my Flutter web app onto AWS Amplify

Tags: amazon-web-services, flutter, aws-amplify, flutter-web

Hi im working on a personal flutter web app project and I was playing around with AWS Amplify

I followed the instructions posted on the flutter web dev page but when I tried to deploy the default flutter web app onto AWS Amplify I got this[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sH0jX.png) so I was wondering if there was a way to deploy my flutter web app onto AWS Amplify or another AWS service

Comment: Hi @omar faheem have you found a solution for this?

Comment: Now, AWS Amplify support flutter web, did you find any good way of doing this?

Answer (score 4):

AWS Amplify currently doesn't have support for Flutter web apps.

There's an [open feature request](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-flutter/issues/234) on the amplify-futter GitHub repo in case you'd like to keep track of this.

Comment: Is there any other AWS service that I can use to do so

Comment: now AWS Amplify support flutter web, but still not good tutorial for deployment :(

Answer (score 0):

As stated by [Ana](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1795003/ana-cunha),  [AWS Amplify](https://aws.amazon.com/amplify/hosting/) doesn't currently have support for Flutter apps

However, There's a workaround using the [peanut](https://pub.dev/packages/peanut) package

This package builds a web version of your Flutter project and places the output in a separate branch, then you could easily connect your Repository to AWS Amplify (or [Github pages](https://pages.github.com/), [Cloudflare Pages](https://pages.cloudflare.com/))

In order to achieve this, do the following on your workstation:

```bash
flutter pub global activate peanut

flutter pub global run peanut -b amplify-production

git push --all
```

I'm currently using Cloudflare pages for one of the production websites built with Flutter, and I am 100% satisfied with the experience.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Now , deploy on  AWS Amplify (Flutter web)

1. Git branch put in web build flutter folder .
2. AWS Amplify chose git hub branch and auto deploy .

Comment: could you please explain more,